# To show Grid/Chart Based on the Button Click

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery, razor

I'm working with MVC3,i've 2 icons  one for Grid and another one for chart when i select Grid icon the page have to show grid and while selecting chart the page should show chart.i'm using following html what jquery code i need to add for particular view?

```
<li>Selected View
    <div class="selectView">
        <a href="#"></a><a href="#"></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: simple idea is to give `hfef="your grid page"` on grid icon and `href="otherpagr"` to other icon

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here, that you have the grid and chart prerendered on your page and that both are hidden. Furthermore I am assuming that your grid has the class `.grid` and your chart has the class `.chart`.

You could write it like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var gridVisible = false,
        chartVisible = false;

    // I'm using the equals (eq) selector because your buttons have no classes
    // to identify them properly
    $(".selectView a:eq(0)").on("click", function() {
        if (gridVisible === false) {
            $(".grid").show();
            gridVisible = true;
        } else {
            $(".grid").hide();
            gridVisible = false;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(".selectView a:eq(1)").on("click", function() {
        if (chartVisible === false) {
            $(".chart").show();
            chartVisible = true;
        } else {
            $(".chart").hide();
            chartVisible = false;
        }
        return false;
    });    
});
```

The button now toggles the visibility of the grid and chart. That means you can show and hide it with the same button. If you're in to design, you could toggle design related classes on the buttons. Like `btn-show` or `btn-hide`. And then add different colors or icons in your CSS styles to it.